# Getting problem to access startDate and endDate using materialui-daterange-picker package in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Here, I have created the redux to store the value and access it anywhere, and yes I am getting the value when the method is getting execute (getting value by the console.) but not able to receive it inside of `promise` to filter the data and render it.

```
    handleChange = (value) => {
    console.log('dateRange handleChange: ', value);
    this.props.addReduxData('dateRange', value)

    // After storing...
    const { dateRange } = this.props
    console.log('dateRange: ', dateRange);

}
```

I also have used the state, to store it and display it, even though it is not rendering in the promise.

Here is the component which is executing `promise` to render the data accordingly.

```
<MaterialTable
                tableRef={this.tableRef}
                title={this.props.title}
                data={query => 
                    
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        
                        console.log('query: ', query)
                        console.log('dateRange Promise: ', this.props.dateRange)
                      
                        if (this.props.dateRange) {
                            console.log('dateRange Called')
                            if (this.props.dateRange.startDate) {
                                query.startDate = moment(this.props.dateRange.startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                            }
                            if (this.props.dateRange.endDate) {
                                query.endDate = moment(this.props.dateRange.endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                            }
                        }
                        
                        console.log('query 273:', query);
                        let filters = []
                        let filter = []

                        if (query) {
                            console.log('query: ', query)
                            console.log('Query Called')
                            if (query.filters) {
                                query.filters.map(filter => {
                                    let value = filter.value
                                    if (Array.isArray(filter.value)) {
                                        value = JSON.stringify(filter.value)
                                    }
                                    filters.push({
                                        name: filter.column.field,
                                        value: value
                                    })
                                    return null
                                })
                            }

                            filter = {
                                page: query.page + 1,
                                pageSize: query.pageSize,
                                search: query.search,
                                orderBy: query.orderBy ? query.orderBy.field : null,
                                orderDirection: query.orderDirection,
                                filters: JSON.stringify(filters),
                            }
                            console.log('query.startDate: ', query.startDate)
                            if (query.startDate) {
                                filter.startDate = query.startDate
                            }
                            console.log('query.endDate: ', query.endDate)
                            if (query.endDate) {
                                filter.endDate = query.endDate
                            }
                        }
                        console.log('props.url:', this.props.url );
                        console.log('query:', query );

                        crudService._getAll(this.props.url, query)
                        .then(
                            result => {
                                if (result.status === 200) {
                                    resolve({
                                        data: result.data.data,
                                        page: result.data.page - 1,
                                        totalCount: Number(result.data.total),
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        );
                    })
                }
                options={options}
                actions={actions}
                columns={finalColumns}
            />
```

I have a function to call the `handleChange` method and after open the modal (`materialui-daterange-picker` modal).

```
openDateRangePicker = () => {
    console.log('dateRange value: ', this.props.dateRange)
    console.log('openDateRangeFilter clicked')
    this.props.showModal({
        open: true,
        dialogWidth: "md",
        something: "something...",
        somethingBoolean: false,
        component: <RenderDateRange open={true} handleChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.getDateRange} />
    })
}
```

What is the problem?
I am getting the stored value and also receiving the value by both methods (`handleChage` and `openDateRangePicker`) but not from the `data` attribute inside the `MaterialTable` component.

My trials: I have tried to call it outside the `promise` and also created a `state` to call it but there wasn't any change or solution.

Please, guide me to resolve it and achieve the solution. So, it will also help others.